# nn.Parameter not getting updated not sure about the usage

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

I have declared two `nn.Parameter()` variables with `requires_grad=True` and I am using those in a different function that's being called inside the init method of the class where variables are declared. `lparam` and `rparam` are not getting updated
My question is am I doing it the right way?
if not how it should be done?

here is the code example:

```
class LG(BaseNetwork):
    def __init__(self, opt):
        super().__init__()
        self.opt = opt
        self.lparam = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1), requires_grad=True).cuda(device=opt.gpu_ids[0])
        self.rparam = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(1), requires_grad=True).cuda(device=opt.gpu_ids[0])
        
    def foo(self, a, b, k=1.0, lparam=0, rparam=0):
      t = bar(a, b, k=k, lparam=lparam, rparam=rparam)
      return t

    def forward(self, a, b):
       x = self.foo(a, b, k=self.opt.k, lparam=self.lparam, rparam=self.rparam)
       return x
```

BaseNetwork is just initializing functions  and uses `nn.Module`

```
def bar(a, b, k=1.0, lparam=0, rparam=0):
    return n(a) * (b.std() * (k * lparam)) + (b.mean() * (k * rparam))
```

When I print the named params I can not get `lparam` and `rparam`

Answer (score 2):

thanks, I got the solution here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nn-parameter-not-getting-updated-not-sure-about-the-usage/157226

I had to remove the `cuda(device=opt.gpu_ids[0])` because it is supposed to get the device that the model is put on.